# Maven implicit profile Activation

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

I have two maven profiles

1. buildProfile
2. testProfile

So whenever i do

> mvn clean install -P buildProfile

it should activate testProfile implicitly first and if testProfile fails it should not proceed to buildProfile and mark the result as Failure.

i want testProfile to be activated only when i run buildprofile.

> mvn clean install -P buildprofile    --> testProfile(if testProfile success then proceed to buildProfile)  +  buildProfile
>
> mvn clean install -P anotherProfile  ---> anotherProfile

is there anyways to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible with Maven's profiles mechanism itself, however you can use profile activation on property, e.g.

```
<activation>
    <property>
        <name>buildProfile</name>
    </property>
</activation>
```

Then the same property can activate multiple profiles. Maven call then looks like this:

```
mvn -DbuildProfile ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can do this by using Jenkins. 
In Jenkins you will have to create 2 jobs, 1 for buildProfile and another for testProfile... and you can create dependency between these two jobs that 'buildProfile' should run only if the 'testProfile' gets passed (complates without any test failures)

Comment: Thanks Sarabjeet .but i'm looking for way to achieve this without the help of jenkins.any idea?

Comment: Hi Hari, I looked into the Maven's documentation, but haven't found such feature. You will have to do this programmatically